# Custom marker on google map as per below image

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-markers

[image]

I want to add custom markers as per follow. I have method for markers on google map, But I want to put users image on marker pin as per below. **I have transparent marker image and I want to load user image from url. So image must dynamic. So I cannot put static markers.**

```
//Add Marker
    func dropMarker(_ location : CLLocation, _ isHotelLocation: Bool = false,_ memberModel : membersModel? = nil){

        let marker = GMSMarker()
        let position =  self.checkIfMutlipleCoordinates(latitude: Float(location.coordinate.latitude), longitude: Float(location.coordinate.longitude))
        marker.position = position

        if isHotelLocation == false{
            if let url = URL.init(string: memberModel!.avatar_url ?? ""){
                let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.init(named: "locationPin"))
                imageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: UIImage.init(named: "locationPin"))
                marker.iconView = imageView
            }else{
                marker.icon = UIImage(named : "LocationPlaceholderPin")
            }

            marker.userData = memberModel
        }else{
            marker.icon = UIImage(named : "hotelMarker")
            hotelLocationMarker = marker
        }

        marker.map = mapView
        arrMarkers.append(marker)
    }
```

Comment: what's the problem ?

Comment: I want to add user's image onto marker as per my image. I want to achieve it. But i am failing to do it

Comment: add user image as subview to your marker image then set that to your marker

Comment: user's image is dynamic, It will be a server url. So How can I add it. Can you give me single example?

Answer (score 0):

Use this extension for downloading image from server:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloaded(from url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {  // for swift 4.2 syntax just use ===> mode: UIView.ContentMode
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
        }.resume()
    }
    func downloaded(from link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {  // for swift 4.2 syntax just use ===> mode: UIView.ContentMode
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloaded(from: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

then add the image as subview to marker image:

```
var userImage = UIImageView()
userImage.downloaded(from: "user image url")
let userMarkerImage = UIImageView(named: "your marker placeholder")
userMarkerImage.addsubView(userImage)
```

then set the image to marker:

```
marker.icon = userMarkerImage
```

> **Note**
>
> You should set the frame of image before adding as subview

Comment: Not working. Only downloaded imageview is showing as marker. Pin is not showing. I want downloaded image on pin

Comment: @JitendraModi you should create that image programmtically

Comment: Ok will try to create dynamic image